# Chemical safety information: Where to look to find out how poisonous poisons are?

Tags: safety, reference-request, toxicity

Could someone point me toward a primer on how to read the toxicity warnings on standard chemical data sheets? Or alternatively, where one should look for more precise information than is contained on such sheets? Specifically, when I see that "Poison" skull and crossbones, I don't know how to tell when it means "Don't drink a quart of it" as versus "If it splashes on your finger, chop it off immediately."

I looked at a data sheet for rosmarinic acid, a component of rosemary, and the Caymen Chemical data sheet it said it was acutely toxic if ingested. So I looked at a data sheet for curcumin, which I have been taking three grams a day of for ten years, and the ThermoFisher data sheet said to seek medical attention immediately if you get any on your skin. That is clearly not right, or I would be dead. Which makes me wonder, in general, where to look for safe levels of exposure, and specifically, how to tell toxic rosemarinic acid (which has been reported to increase the average lifespan of c. elegans by 63 percent*) is to humans.

- Biogerontology 12(4): 329–347. doi:10.1007/s10522-011-9334-7.  Biofactors 45(5): 774–787. doi: 10.1002/biof.1536.

Comment: Indeed reading the safety data sheets is a bit confusing. NaCl is quite surprising as well. One important point - I guess - is that they serve as regulatory in industrial environment. So I am not surprised to read about NaCl, but then I am confused while reading about chemicals which are exotic even for a chemist....